# BulletSpan not adding a bullet

Tags: android

I've been trying to create a list of strings with bullet points to the left of them using BulletSpan but it's not working. The list of string is being displayed, but with no bullet to the left of them. I've researched a fair bit and it seems that bullets only come after a new line, so I've added "\r\n" before each string but this isn't working either.

For context, the object mModule contains a RealmList of strings called bullets, and I'm trying to set the group of bullet pointed strings to "thingsToTv".

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < mModule.getBullets().size(); i++){
            String stringB = "\r\n" + mModule.getBullets().get(i);
            SpannableString string = new SpannableString(stringB);
            string.setSpan(new BulletSpan(), 0, stringB.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            Log.d(TAG, "String: " + string);
            sb.append(stringB);
        }

        thingsToTv.setText(sb);
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with `RealmList` but if it is like an `ArrayList` then you can try this:

```
SpannableString spanString;

private void testSpanBullet(){
    String sep = System.lineSeparator();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Test 1");
    list.add("Test 2");
    list.add("Test 3");
    list.add("Test 4");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(String s : list){
        sb.append(sep + s);
    }

    String concat = sb.toString();
    spanString = new SpannableString(concat);

    for(String s : list){
        addBullet(s, concat);
    }

    textView.setText(spanString);
}

private void addBullet(String s, String txt){
    int index = txt.indexOf(s);
    // You can change the attributes as you need ... I just added a bit of color and formating
    BulletSpan bullet = new BulletSpan(20, Color.RED);
    spanString.setSpan(bullet, index, index+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

---

**Note:**
This will only work if the values in the your `RealmList` are unique.


**Also if `RealmList` doesn't allow the `foreach` then you will need to do the `for`loop as you did in your code `for(int i = 0; i < mModule.getBullets().size(); i++)`**

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.. Thanks for your help. I've implemented this code, and the bullet points are showing and as you say, it only works if all values are different which should be fine once a full API response is available to me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When setting the text on textview, try to use the following code.

Instead of:

```
thingsToTv.setText(sb);
```

**Try this**

```
thingsToTv.setText(sb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```